# Chaining API calls with $q.all

Tags: angularjs

I don't know
 how to add the returned data from resource to the promise array correctly. When I log it to the console its empty.

Here is my code:

```
var d = $q.defer();
var promises = [];
_.each(recipe.credentials, function(credential) {
    APIService.save({route:'credential'},credential).$promise.then(function(data) {
        promises.push(data)
    });
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    d.resolve();
});

return d.promise;
```

Updated Code:

```
var d = $q.defer();
var promises = recipe.credentials.map(function(credential) {
    return APIService.save({route:'credential'},credential).$promise;
});
return $q.all(promises)
```

Comment: Don't know...but it works with .save!

Comment: Forget creating the deferred object, just `return $q.all(...`. You'll probably want to `return data` in the `then` handler too if you expect to access it outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap promises when they're created, and don't forget the `.catch` handler:

```
$q.all(recipe.credentials.map(function(credential) {
  return APIService.save({route:'credential'},credential).$promise;
})).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); 
}).catch(function(reason) {
  console.log(reason); 
});
```

Also, most probably there's no need to create another defer - just return the result of `$q.all` into outer world.

P.S. I highly recommend reading [this article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) about promises and their usage. )

Comment: Maybe it's your whacky bracket / brace / newline style ;)

Comment: Well, that's just for example. I found it easier to distinguish between mapper function and callback one (supplied into `.then`). But anyway, rewrote this in a more plain way. )

Comment: Theew is no data and reason logged in the console...but the server receive and return it correctly. Any idea? I updated code in start post.

Comment: @nofear87 Check your browser's *Network* tab and make sure all the requests look right and that the responses are successful and look how you expect them to

Comment: @Phil The posts are pending. But it must be a client problem.

Comment: @nofear87 well that's why you're not seeing anything. Your API isn't responding

Comment: ... because it's most probably has omitted `.catch` handler (or similar thing) too. ) That was actually our case.

Comment: @raina77ow doubt it. The requests in the *Network* console should still resolve if the API responds. How it's handled in JS doesn't matter

Comment: @Phil: you are right! I only returned the data without res.send! That was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Phil No, I actually meant the server-side part. ) In our case, it was even more complicated because it was kind of screened by the proxy infrastructure.